# Filling dataframe with loops

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Start <- data.frame("Number" = 2,"Square" = 4,"Cube" = 8)
```

A Vector of inputs:

```
Numbers <- c(3,5)
```

I want to iterate the elements of Numbers in the function Squarecube and fill the dataframe with the results:

```
 SquareCube <- function(x){ df <- c(x^2,x^3) 
df}
```

Desired Output:

```
 Filled <- data.frame("Number" = c(2,3,5),"Square" = c(4,9,25),"Cube" = c(8,27,125))
```

Note: Already searched for this topic , but in this case the size of the vector Numbers can be different. My intent is to fill the dataframe with the results of the function.

Thanks

Comment: `Numbers <- c(2,3,5); SquareCube <- function(x) {c(x, x^2, x^3)}; sapply(Numbers, SquareCube)` You don't need a df before, just a vector with numbers, final output is matrix, but you can transform it into df

Comment: It worked, but after I converted to data frame, i couldn´t filter the elements ( numbers)

Comment: What do you mean by filter?

Comment: When I use the function View on the data frame it displays the message: " Failure to sort or filter data"

Comment: I don't know how is this related to you original problem and I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question right, you may just be having issues with structure that `do.call` may be able to help with. I also redefined the function slightly to accommodate the naming:

```
Start <- data.frame("Number" = 2,"Square" = 4, "Cube" = 8)
Number <- c(3,5)
```

Define your function:

```
SquareCube <- function(x){ list(Number=x,Square=x^2,Cube=x^3) }
```

Then construct the data frame with desired end results:

```
> rbind(Start, data.frame(  do.call(cbind, SquareCube(Number))  ))
  Number Square Cube
1      2      4    8
2      3      9   27
3      5     25  125
```

You can also make a wrapper function and just hand it the `Start` data and the original `Number` list that you want to process, which will yield a data frame:

```
> makeResults <- function(a, b) { rbind(a, data.frame(do.call(cbind,SquareCube(b)))) }
> makeResults(Start, Number)
  Number Square Cube
1      2      4    8
2      3      9   27
3      5     25  125
```

Answer (score 1):

`outer()` function produces matrix which has exactly same output of yours. You can just change it to data frame and rename.

```
(Filled <- outer(
  c(2, 3, 5),
  1:3,
  FUN = "^"
))

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    4    8
#> [2,]    3    9   27
#> [3,]    5   25  125
```

For this matrix, you can use any function what you know to

1. change class
2. change column names

Here, for instance, `dplyr::rename()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Filled %>%
  as_tibble() %>% # make data frame
  rename(Number = V1, Square = V2, Cube = V3) # rename column names

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Number Square  Cube
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      2      4     8
#> 2      3      9    27
#> 3      5     25   125
```